# Cypress: How to wait and then read innertext of an element that will only appear somewhere between 30 seconds to 120 seconds

Tags: loops, variables, global, cypress

I have a requirement whereby once I sign-up for a user registration my ID gets generated in the back-end and the web page shows that ID nearly after somewhere between 30 seconds to 120 seconds.

So when I use:

```
cy.get('header > p').invoke('text').then('text' => {
    cy.log("User Id: " + text)
})
```

I may not have it just after the sign-up is complete, so I need to wait in a loop check every 10 seconds or so until the User Id is displayed as part of the selector 'header > p'

Tried different looping logics etc., incl. wait and check, but due to async nature of the requests the variable scoping is not working for me, hence tried cy.wrap('false').as('found') and then tried to use that in cy.get(this.found), but once that i need to chain that into .then.

So is there an easy way to store a global variable value using command.js perhaps? Which I can update in

```
while(!variableFound) {
cy.get('header > p').invoke('text').then('text' => {
    cy.log("User Id: " + text)
    if(text.length > 0) {
        variableFound = true
    } else {
        variableFound = false
    }
})
}
```

Finally tried the following code from a forum, even when User Id is available inside header>p tag it keeps failing to identify that.

```
    let found = false
    let count=0
    while (!found) {

        const nonExistent = Cypress.$('header > p')

        // this is always evaluating to 0 even when p is become available and contains has the text
        cy.log("Length: " + nonExistent.length) 

        if (!nonExistent.length) {                                
            cy.visit("/profile/")                
            found = false
            count=count+1
            cy.wait(5000)
            cy.visit("/dashboard/")

            if(count==18) {
                found = true
                cy.log('Element not found after 18 attempts.Exit from loop!!!')
            }
        } else {
            found = true
            cy.get('header > p').invoke('text').then((useridtext) => {
                cy.log("User Id: " + useridtext)
            })
        }
    }
```

Any advise is sincerely appreciated. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to both @RichardMatsen and Arnon Axelrod, below is the recursive function that works for me.

```
/* Recursive function */
function getEnvironment() {
    function getEnvironmentInternal(retires) {
        if (retires == 0) {
            throw "text didn't appear after the specified retires";
        }
        return cy.get('header > p').invoke('text').then(text => {
            if(text) {
                 return cy.wrap(text);
            }

            cy.wait(10000);
            cy.reload();
            return getEnvironmentInternal(retires-1);
        });
    }
    return getEnvironmentInternal(12);
 }

/* Usage */
getEnvironment().then(text => {
    cy.log("User Id: " + text);
});
```

---

As at Nov 2020, this problem may be solved with [Test Retries](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/test-retries.html).

Answer (score 4):

The problem is not all command chains apply the [automatic retry mechanism](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/retry-ability.html#Commands-vs-assertions) as you might expect.

So `cy.get('header > p').invoke('text')` retries the first part (looking for the element) but as soon as the element is present, it grabs whatever text it has at that time.

The `cy.contains()` command is better for retrying until both the element and the right content is present.

Since it can take up to 120 seconds, you have to extend the retry timeout.

Ref [cy.contains()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/contains.html#Syntax), the 4th pattern `.contains(selector, content, options)`.

Some ideas,

**If you know what user id will be sent**

Do this if you always get a known user id, of if you can stub the call and return a value for testing.

```js
cy.contains('header > p', 'expectedUserId', { timeout: 120000 })
  .invoke('text')
  .then(text => cy.log("User Id: " + text) )
```

---

**If you only know the general form of user id that will be sent**

Use a **regexp** if you don't know the exact user id, but know it's form (e.g always a number).

```js
cy.contains('header > p', /\d+/, { timeout: 120000 })
  .invoke('text')
  .then(text => cy.log("User Id: " + text) )
```

---

**If you know that the element will be empty before user id arrives**

Use a **regexp** for non-empty content.

```js
cy.contains('header > p', /.+/, { timeout: 120000 })
  .invoke('text')
  .then(text => cy.log("User Id: " + text) )
```

Comment: Many thanks for your detailed answer and I tried cy.contains and it looks like it would do the job for me, but I have to refresh the page for the <p>userid</p> to appear. By default the page only shows <header>...</header> and when I refresh the page it creates the <p>userid</p> element under <header>

So that's why I was trying to use a loop-wait-check kind of logic, while cy.contains is better than my implementation of cy.get().invoke(), I still somehow need to refresh the page for the <p> element to appear?

Comment: Does this behavior only happen when running the app through Cypress, or also when running in a browser?

Comment: When running the app in a browser too, the behaviour end user is expected is same. In a real world the end user has few options to click around various menus and eventually when they get back to their landing page (dashboard) they would be presented with their user id. Also in DB it gets generated almost instantaneous, it is just that the front end is not using any websockets or anything of that sort to provide the id without refreshing dashboard page.

Comment: Your 2nd code sample is how I would recommend doing it, using `Cypress.$('header > p')` to check instead of `cy.get()`. But I'm not sure that the loop is waiting as you need it to - the commands run somewhat independently of the test javascript. If you add a few `console.log()`s into various parts of the loop you can see the order that things execute in.

Comment: Just tried a mock-up, if you change `cy.log()` to `console.log()` you can see they hit count 18 very quickly, but the command's still chug on.

Comment: Thank you Richard Matsen, I found a similar question here in SO just now
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58770726/using-for-loop-and-if-else-in-cypress).

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58770726/using-for-loop-and-if-else-in-cypress

@arnon-axelrod - thanks for providing a recursion example for looping. 

I changed little to get it working for me. I'll post that as a separate comment below, might help someone else.

Comment: Thank you, up voted Arnon's answer in the link above.